# Maven generated-sources Ignore optional compile problems

Tags: eclipse, m2e

I would like to be able to automatically setup our eclipse projects to *Ignore optional compile problems* using m2e, but I seem to run into a conflict of m2e vs maven.

If I use the build-helper-maven-plugin to add source directories, it's great - I don't have to automatically add the `generated-sources/annotations` to my eclipse project.  But if I do that, every time m2e Updates the eclipse project (alt+f5), it removes any manual configuration I've added to the source directores (including the *Ignore optional compile problems*).

So currently, my workaround is to manually add the generated-sources directories to the eclipse projects so that I don't constantly get all those warnings back on generated code.

(My use case is using dagger, which has a lot of generated code, but in very different formats from the rest of our code base, is not java8 based, etc, so we get lots of format and style warnings).

One answer may be to try out the Annotation Processing in m2e, but I've had issues with that in the past conflicting with maven on the command line and other issues, and I'm not sure it would address this issue anyhow.  Even the choices in the list for Annotation Processing Mode both list the deficiencies.

Can anyone think of any other workarounds, until the [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388541) is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

The [bug is finally fixed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388541#c14) in M2E 1.6.2 (1.6.2/Mars RC2).